# Is it a good idea to use Neo4J for user data storage and authentication with Passport.Js / Node.Js

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j, passport.js

I want to set up user data storage and authentication with Passport.Js / Node.Js running on Express with Neo4J database. Haven't seen any examples of anyone doing that. Is there a particular reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a system using Neo4j and want to add authentication, it would be silly to introduce a new piece of infrastructure just to manage lists of users with their hashed passwords.

As for the first example: it is entirely possible that noone has gotten around to doing this, or at least they haven't shared it. Please do the work and blog about it for future users? ;)

Comment: I heard some security concerns about using Neo4J for user data storage. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: No. But I should probably divulge I am a developer at Neo Technology... Anyway as far as security goes, you 1) never store plaintext passwords, just hashed ones, 2) ensure your instance is secure, and 3) ensure traffic is encrypted (HTTPS). That means no authorised access to the machine itself, and you must use authentication if the box is internet-facing. May I ask what your setup looks like? Do you host on e.g. AWS?

Comment: Ok, so it's good to hear from a specialist there is no concerns :) I'll host on WebFaction VPS, it's an app running on Express / Passport / Node.Js with Neo4J database.

Comment: Does that mean WebFaction host Neo4j for you, as a service? I have no experience with them. It is important to note that Neo4j doesn't have authentication built in, but we have tips for what you can do: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html

Comment: That would mean that I'd host Neo4J there myself. Haven't tried yet, but they said it should work...

Comment: Neo4j is as good as any other database technology for storing user data. The thing that matters most is, as lassewesth pointed out, following a good security policy for data transmission/access.